# bash set variable with process substitution

Tags: bash

I am running a command which writes to a file, but I want to effectively write to a variable instead. Something like the following:

```bash
echo test | tee >(var=$(cat)) >/dev/null && echo "var = $var"
```

I want this to output `var = test`, but since the variable assignment in the process substitution runs in a separate process, the var variable is not set in the outer scope.

What are some options for doing this?

Keep in mind that my command (tee in the example) outputs stuff to stdout that I want to discard.

I do not want to create temporary files.

Comment: `echo test | tee >(var=$(cat) ; printf 'var = %s\n' "$var")`

Comment: Not sure how you would achieve it outside of the subshell, but hey life is full of surprises!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ...

> Keep in mind that my command (tee in the example) outputs stuff to stdout that I want to discard.

... I think you're telling us that the `tee` in the example command is a stand-in for some other program in the cases that are of most interest to you.

I note also that you say you have a command that *writes to* a file.  Although `tee` is indeed such a command, the particular command line you provide contains a typo.  The file names given on the `tee` command line are used as *output* files, whereas `<(var=$(cat))` is open for reading.  I guess you meant the example to be something more like this:

```
echo test | my_program >(var=$(cat)) >/dev/null && echo "var = $var"
```

, though that still doesn't work, of course.

Bottom line: you want to capture a command's output to a file instead of its standard output, without introducing a temporary file.

It looks like you are using most of the right tools for such a job, but not putting them together in a way that works.  If you want to avoid a temporary file then I don't see any way around performing the command substitution at the top level:

```
var=$(...) && echo "var = ${var}"
```

And it turns out that this `>(cat)` works as a pseudo-file that sends everything written to it to the `cat`'s standard output.  Putting all that together, then, you get this:

```
var=$(echo test | my_program >(cat) >/dev/null) && echo "var = ${var}"
```

Note well that in that command, the redirection of `my_program`'s standard output is irrelevant to `cat`.  The `cat` command inherits its standard output from the subshell environment introduced by the command substitution, which is exactly what that command substitution captures.

Note also that the pipeline needs to be inside the command substitution for the variable assignment to be at "top level", as described above.  That is, you cannot do this ...

```
# DOES NOT WORK
echo test | { var=$(my_program >(cat) >/dev/null); } && echo "var = ${var}"
```

... because the pipeline introduces a subshell environment for each component command, much like the command substitution does for its command.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Before now, I did not understand the semantics of process substitution with output redirection. Indeed I had a typo in the original question. I have correct it now.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it because the code is confusing (piping into a shell assignment ?! ) and errorprone (usually fails, as you state) but with `set +m` and `shopt -s lastpipe`, your "DOES NOT WORK" example will actually work.

Answer (score 4):

If your OS supports /dev/fd/, try this:

```
var=$(echo "test" | tee /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Explanation: The `3>&1` makes the shell open file descriptor #3 for the `tee` program as duplicate of the original stdout (which the `$( )` is capturing); then the `>/dev/null` replaces that stdout with one directed to `/dev/null` (discarding it). With those redirects in place, `tee /dev/fd/3` sends its output to file descriptor #3 (which is still going to be captured by the `$()`).

Answer (score 2):

```
var=$( echo test | tee >(cat) >/dev/null ) && echo "var = $var"
```

?

Comment: An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems to work. An explanation would be helpful. Why isn't the output of cat redirected to /dev/null?

Comment: @DBear John Bollinger seems to have done the explanation before I came back. Like him, I wasn't sure what you were asking but we made the same assumptions. Gordon Davisson's edited answer is basically the same as ours but is probably more efficient since no intermediate cat process is needed. However it relies on choosing a file descriptor that the command is not already using.